# Is Camel doWhile a real do-while?

Tags: while-loop, apache-camel, do-while

I read in the [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/loop-eip.html) that we can use looping with a `doWhile` construct.

But it is not clear to me: does the Camel's `doWhile` behaves like a classic `do-while` (executing at least once without condition), or it is more like the `while` construct (executing only if condition is true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested, and it seems equivalent to the `while` construct.